# Как рисовать в Matplotlib в комплексных координатах?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Требуется изобразить вот такую функцию:

```
w(omega) = 1/(1 + 1j*omega)
```

в комплексных координатах. Как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот такой вариант вам не подойдет?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
omega = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)
w = 1 / (1 + 1j*omega)
plt.figure(1)
plt.scatter(w.real, w.imag)
plt.show()
```